# Visual paradigm: nested collaborations

Tags: uml, visual-paradigm

I'm trying to create nested collaboration, just like that: [image]

But, in fact, `Collaboration 2` isn't sub-node of `Collaboration 1`: [image]

So, say, when I drag first one (bigger), second one stays on its place. I have to select both items (`Collaboration 1` and `Collaboration 2`) and then drag. And similar issues, which are annoying.

I tried many things to get what I need, but it seems impossible. Am I doing/understanding something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I need to use `Model` instead of `Collaboration`. Models can be nested. No idea why Collaborations couldn't though, but, it's not principal for me, so, problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would like to model something in the old UML 1.x. In UML 2 you should model it with the Composite Structure Diagram instead. More details about drawing the Composite Structure Diagram can be found at

http://linkvp.com/rxwvajog

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Composite Structure Diagram does not seem to be what I need: this diagram should be completely encapsulated, and other entities should communicate with it using ports. But, in my particular case, I need to communucate directly with classes from collaboration.   I already found the solution: I need to use "Model" instead of "Collaboration". I still don't understand why Collaborations couldn't be nested, but Models can, so I'm glad. =)